# Google Chrome not working on Windows. IE-tab with-in Chrome and Chrome App work

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, ietab

OK, I recently have been having issues with Google Chrome on my laptop computer. Last night I could not get Chrome to work at all at home. I figured it was just a one-night event; however, today at work, I still could not get it working!

All my coworkers can get their Internet working, but I cannot.

I was doing some experimenting, and noticed that...

- I can get **IE Tab** *within* Chrome to display webpages!
- I can get **Windows 8 mode** working for Chrome, and that allows me to display webpages!

The only thing that I cannot get working is my standard Google Chrome.

Where can I start to figure out how to fix this?

Comment: What's IE tab within Chrome?

Comment: IE Tab -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en

Comment: Did you try resetting Chrome? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en

Comment: I didn't do anything (no resetting), but it now seems to just work. I will see what it is like when I get home.